# How do i add a grid behindthe areas in R's areaplot()?

Tags: r, plot, area

How do i add a grid behind the areas when using `areaplot()` in R?
I tried it with `grid()` but it does only show the grid structure in front of the areas.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following approach.

First, we load the `areaplot` package and create some dummy data to work with (since none were supplied in the question):

```r
# Load packages
library(areaplot)

# Make dummy data
set.seed(1) # Makes example reproducible
data <- rpois(10, 40)
```

Next we create a normal R plot of our data, but make the points invisible. Then we add a grid using `grid()`

```r
# Create empty plot with appropriate axes and grid
plot(data, type = "n")
grid()
```

Finally, we draw our area plot, using the `add = TRUE` parameter to ensure that we are drawing on the existing plot rather than starting a new plot from scratch:

```
# Generate area plot
areaplot(data, add = TRUE)
```

[image]